# BaseX XQuery does not return the root element

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

I am trying to use an `XQuery` search like this with `BaseX`:

```
XQUERY doc("ann-20140201.xml")//xbrl
```

I am submitting a small excerpt from the [original](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/874214/000087421414000008/ann-20140201.xml) instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:ann="http://www.anninc.com/20140201" xmlns:dei="http://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2013-01-31" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:us-gaap="http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2013-01-31" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <link:schemaRef xlink:href="ann-20140201.xsd" xlink:type="simple" />
  <xbrli:context id="FD2011Q4YTD">
    <xbrli:entity>
      <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://www.sec.gov/CIK">0000874214</xbrli:identifier>
    </xbrli:entity>
    <xbrli:period>
      <xbrli:startDate>2011-01-30</xbrli:startDate>
      <xbrli:endDate>2012-01-28</xbrli:endDate>
    </xbrli:period>
  </xbrli:context>
  <xbrli:context id="FD2011Q4YTD_ann_EarningsPerShareReconciliationAxis_ann_EarningsPerShareBasic.Member">
    <xbrli:entity>
```

However even if it is **clear** that `<xbrl>` is the **root** element when i Execute the Query with `BaseX` it returns nothing!

How is it possible to return nothing when the equivalent command returns the root?

The *equivalent command* is:

```
XQUERY doc("ann-20140201.xml")//*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your root element is `{http://xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl`. Your query is looking for `xbrl`. They're not the same thing.

Try:

```
declare namespace xbrli=http://xbrl.org/2003/instance;
doc("ann-20140201.xml")//xbrli:xbrl
```

Comment: Wow~ How can an attribute be the root element? i mean we have the "<" symbol and next to it the element name. Please clue me in a bit.

Comment: @Codo, the root element starts with `<xbrli:xbrl>`. The part on the left of the `:` specifies the namespace, and there's an `xmlns:xbrli` giving the URL it points to.

Comment: I believe it is this one however `xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"`. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the namespace declaration used for any element in its scope with its name starting with `xbrli:`.

Answer (score 6):

As the previous answer have already shown, you need to specify the namespace URI. This is one more way to do it:

```
doc("ann-20140201.xml")//Q{http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance}xbrl
```

If you are a lazy typer, you may as well use a wildcard:

```
doc("ann-20140201.xml")//*:xbrl
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a namespace issue. Namespaces are especially important if combining XML from different sources, eg. embedding (X)HTML in RSS feeds, where some elements might share the same names but have different meanings.

To solve the problem, register and use this namespace:

```
declare namespace xbrli = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";
doc("ann-20140201.xml")//xbrli:xbrl
```

Both lines can be joined to a single line if you want to continue using the command input field.